# The best approximation method to recover original polygon outline before rasterization procedure

Tags: approximation, polygons

I have a polygon, originally created as a Bézier Curve (black outline on the picture), and then saved as a polygon with enough points to call it smooth (at this scale). Then this polygon was rasterized (binarized), the borders of this polygon were converted to vector format (the red outline on the picture).

**I want to restore the original line from rasterized using the approximation method.**

What is the best way to do this?

By “best method” I mean a method that will return the same original boundary (black outline) or the closest result to the original line.

____________[image]

Comment: Take a look at Lempitsky, "[Surface Extraction from Binary Volumes
with Higher-Order Smoothness](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vilem/cvpr2010b.pdf)" (CVPR 2010).

Comment: You have flagged to have this question moved to gis.stackexchange.com. However, it is not currently a good fit for gis.stackexchange.com. As there are no votes or answers here, an appropriate course of action for you would be to delete this question and just ask a good question on gis.stackexchange.com. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be accomplished with [Savitzky–Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) filter. There is implementation of this algorithm [here](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter). Because `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` only accept 1-demention arrays - the trick is to pass `X` and `Y` coordinates of the polygon to the function separately.

I am still figuring out which parameters is the best to use.